# How to share the Particular SQLITE audio file to Gmail in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite, share, audio-recording

I am working audio recording app, in which the audio is recorded and stored inside the app and that path is stored in SQLITE.

I need that audio file to be shared in whatsapp/gmail or saved in internal directory of mobile.

I try to share them using the Intent but in whatsapp it showed unsupported format.

I tried this code

```
    private void Shareoption(List<RecordData> uploadlist)
{
    RecordData reco2 = uploadlist.get(0);
    String id3 = reco2.getId();
    final RecordData recordData = DBcreatedata.getData(id3);
    final File f;
    locname =   recordData.getRecordDataTitle();
    f = new File(recordData.getRecordData());

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(f.getAbsolutePath() );
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri.toString());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

And I also searched about this and I came to know that first the audio file must be stored in internal directory before sharing. So I tried input output stream method, it did not work.

Can any one help me to share this audio file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this I think your problem will be solved

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri shareFileUri= Uri.parse(string);
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
sharingIntent.setType("*/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareFileUri);
sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Sound File"));
```

Comment: Same error bro, "The file format is not supported".
Is their is anyway to copy the audio file to internal storage, so that i can use that location and share them in whatsapp or gmail.

Comment: when you getting the path from the database is there any file that exists on that path

Comment: bro, i found the error and fixed it , your code is working for whatsapp but when i try to attach that audio file to email its not attaching the file. can you tell me why? do i have to add any package name in share option

Comment: I am using this as an attachment also to the email bro

Comment: I think you should use these two flags in the intent to resolve your issue

Comment: sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); add this befoew setType and sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  below the putextra

Comment: I think this may help you

Comment: ok bro thanks for your help, i will add this code and check, and let you know about it.